# adding strings as numbers

Tags: string

I'm trying to add together two large numbers, stored as strings.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function addBigNums(a,b){
  c = ""; // output
  o = 0;  // carryover

  startLen = a.length-1;
  for(i = startLen; i >= 0; i--) {
   sum = parseInt(a[i], 10) + parseInt(b[i], 10) + o; 
   c = (sum % 10) + c; 
   o = sum >= 10;      
  }

  if(o === true) c = "1" + c;
  return c;
}
```

I'm running into two issues:

1 ) my carry is not always functioning properly, primarily when:

2 ) the numbers length differ.

Right now I think I would have to prepend 0's onto the shorter number in order to get this to function as expected.

Any better alternatives to this?

Comment: why not just do addition and carry-over on each pair of individual digits?  Grade-school algebra style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, straightforward integer addition like you would do it manually:

```
a = "123456";       // input a
b = "123456";       // input b
c = "";             // target-string
o = 0;              // overflow-bit

// traverse string from right to left
for(i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

     // do the calculation (with overflow bit)
     sum = parseInt(a[i]) + parseInt(b[i]) + o;

     // prepend resulting digit to target
     c = (sum % 10) + c;

     // set overflow bit for next round
     o = sum >= 10;
}

// prepend another "1" if last overflow-bit is true
if(o == true) c = "1" + c;
```

If strings a and b are not equal length (but you stated that they are), you should prepend the shorter string with zeros before calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider both numbers to be an array of digits. Add them up right-to-left handling overflow flag. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vF6E5/1/). Assuming your numbers are of the same length

```
function getNumber(len) {
    return Array.apply(null, new Array(len)).map(function(){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
    }).join('');
}

var len = 600,
    a = getNumber(len), //use your numbers here
    b = getNumber(len),
    flag = 0;

var c = [].reduceRight.call(a, function(acc, val, idx) {
    val = +val + (+b.charAt(idx)) + flag;
    flag = val / 10 | 0;
    val %= 10;
    return val + acc;
}, '');

c = (flag ? 1: '') + c;

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Comment: you could prefix the strings with 0s to make them the same length -- this would solve the "not the same length" issue in an easy way.

Comment: Doesn't seem correct.  2435476587872034729384659813465923659182365981236591823651982365129356 + 1123751283518235187235408721354012351239651238561029356120935612395120956129835629836501293650123650129375610297356120389571620 =  3559227871390269916620068534819936010422017219797621179772917977524476.  That doesn't work because the result has fewer digits than the longest number

Comment: @NewAlexandria: **Assuming your numbers are of the same length**